# How to fix error from posting html element and prevent it from running

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, debugging

I'm debugging my website,
I found out that when i post html,css and php program using post article 
it will run as posted how can i fix this so it will not affect my website again

**EXAMPLE**

When i submit something like this

```
<style>
*{
display:none!important;
}
</style>
```

On the whole page will display none instead of showing what the user post.
**Another example**

```
<form>
<input type="text" value="Hello"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
<form>
```

Also this html form will run as html instead of displaying the text
Please how can i fix this in my php to avoid this.
I have try to add this `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post']);` in my php before it post to my database but still not working can anyone help me

**Here is my php to submit post**

```
<?php

if($_POST){
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_pass = "pass";
    $db_name = "posts";

    try {
         $db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",$db_user,$db_pass);
         $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
         $stmt = $db_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO posts(post) VALUES(:post)");

         $stmt->bindParam(':post', $post); 

         $form = $_POST;
         $post= mysql_real_escape_string($form['post']);

         $stmt->execute();

         echo "Post submited";

    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $db_conn = null;
}
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` doesn't play well with PDO and is unneeded since you're using prepared statements. `$form = $_POST` is only reassigning the array, sit is is unnecessary as well.

Comment: @JayBlanchard how else can i prevent that from happening is affecting on my page and as for `mysql_real_escape_string()` and `$form = $_POST` i wasn't using it before i user this for post `$post = $_POST['post']`

Comment: You have to have name attributes for your form elements or nothing will get posted.

Comment: In fact using `mysql_real_escape_string()` should be generating Errors as you have not connected using the `mysql_` extension. **So start by looking at your php error log**. If that is empty then change the `php.ini` parameter `display_errors = On`. If you dont have access to `php.ini` because you are developing on a LIVE Server then Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use htmlentities() function because it converts all applicable characters to HTML entities :

```
htmlentities ($form['post'])
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: This what i get when i post something like this `<style>*{display:none;}</style>` i get this in out put `*{display:none;}`  and when i post input it also show the input as html @JayBlanchard